# svg path, that has property stroke-dashoffset and svg "fill" on page scroll in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

I ve been trying to find how to achieve svg path, that has property stroke-dashoffset and svg "fill" on page scroll,its been done on this website: https://asaro.co.uk/

Comment: this is `svg path`, that has property `stroke-dashoffset` and svg "fill" on page scroll https://monosnap.com/file/9UMtNfssBFxtB6OnHSYo2aYhBpXAA3

Comment: i think it's something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jzsbfr7k/, tweak the css values to what ever looks to you.

Comment: @20yco thank you for translating what i was trying to find. :)

Comment: @MohammedNadeem give me 10 minutes i will show you something similar

Comment: [`<path>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) is a shape element in the SVG library. In other words, It's a type of `<svg>` element. [`stroke-dashoffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset) is an SVG property common to a large number of SVG elements, not only to `<path>`. The animations you are looking for are SMIL animations and do not work in IE.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, tutorial, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. If you cannot find a resource that does what you want it to, then you'll need to write your own.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function(e){

  var d = d || parseInt($('.c-line.c-line--fill-2').css('stroke-dashoffset'));

  var lastScrollTop = 0;
       st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(st < lastScrollTop) {
            if( d <= 1800){
              d += $(this).scrollTop() / 20;
            }
        }
        else {
          if( d >= 0){
            d -= $(this).scrollTop() / 20;
          }
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;


$('.c-line.c-line--fill-2').css('stroke-dashoffset', d );

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000; 
  height:1000px;
}

.c-line-wrap {
    position: absolute;
}

.c-line-wrap svg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.c-line {
    fill: none;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.c-line--fill-1 {
    stroke: #404150;
}

.c-line--fill-2 {
    stroke: #fff;
}

.c-line--dashed {
    stroke: #131424;
    stroke-dasharray: 5 5;
    stroke-width: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1327.78 2952.52" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <path class="c-line c-line--fill c-line--fill-1" d="M.11.49s415.15,96,291.15,576-132,896,340,1284,732,472,692,1092" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
            <path class="c-line c-line--fill c-line--fill-2 js-line--fill" d="M.11.49s415.15,96,291.15,576-132,896,340,1284,732,472,692,1092" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" style="stroke-dashoffset: 1800; stroke-dasharray: 1879.02px, 1889.02px;"></path>
            <path class="c-line c-line--dashed" d="M.11.49s415.15,96,291.15,576-132,896,340,1284,732,472,692,1092" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></path>
        </svg>
</div>
```

Something like this, but remember, this is **AS IS** and this is **only** to understand to question starter how it probably can work:

**[MAGIC FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nicklev/97mj0rkd/)**

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, i will try it out and modify it accordingly. :)

Comment: @MohammedNadeem no problem, read more about `scrollTop()` events and how work with it

Comment: so here's my attempt to make the svg work but i cant seem to get the animation on the stroke. http://ims.nadeembuilds.com/ , this is the example https://asaro.co.uk/ , this is what i want to achieve : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/deda39c8bce444c1e1c90b8baea1e7f820190202152620/d0776f88dc8b69b1ae43afc048ab980720190202152620/fbb0c5

Comment: @MohammedNadeem can't see CSS and JS from my example in your page, add js and css and test it

Comment: I have implemented that css js with our svg but still not working on local page ,as on example svg having three path and our svg having only one path.